# How to calculate the total proportional change in abundance based on GLMM predicted values in R?

Tags: r, statistics, lme4, proportions, glmm

I am now dealing with the analysis of a long term bird survey, that was conducted every 3 years since 2004. For each species, I used lme4 package to fit a GLMM with the abundance as the response variable, year and sampling effort as the predictos and transect as the random effect:

```
model <-  glmer(Sum_Abundance ~ Year + Sampling.Effort + (1|Transect), family = poisson, data = nestingbirds)
```

Next, i want to use metrics of proportional loss (i.e., percent decline) to facilitate comparison of population trends across species -  I want to calculate the total proportional change in abundance (i.e., the change in the population integrated over the entire study period).The aim is to estimate how much a population changed in abundance since the study began.

For each species, I want to extract the slope associated with year (i.e. predicted number of unique individuals observed per year), and use the predicted values from the model to charachterize if the trend is increasing, decreasing, or has no change. In addition, I want to know if the trends are significant or not.

Does someone have the idea what is the code for this proccess in R?

Here is the data frame for the model:

```
structure(list(Year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), levels = c("2004", "2007", "2010", 
"2013", "2017", "2020", "2023"), class = "factor"), Transect = c("East", 
"East", "East", "North", "North", "North", "West", "West", "West", 
"East", "East", "East", "East", "North", "North", "North", "North", 
"West", "West", "West", "West", "East", "East", "East", "North", 
"North", "North", "West", "West", "West", "East", "East", "East", 
"East", "North", "North", "North", "North", "West", "West", "West", 
"West", "East", "East", "East", "East", "North", "North", "North", 
"North", "West", "West", "West", "West", "East", "East", "East", 
"East", "North", "North", "North", "North", "West", "West", "West", 
"West", "East", "East", "East", "East", "North", "North", "North", 
"North", "West", "West", "West", "West"), Repetition = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), Sum_Abundance = c(15L, 
25L, 7L, 10L, 17L, 15L, 12L, 9L, 13L, 6L, 7L, 12L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 
7L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 15L, 21L, 21L, 20L, 19L, 18L, 9L, 12L, 
7L, 14L, 10L, 7L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 9L, 5L, 12L, 
11L, 17L, 11L, 4L, 5L, 15L, 12L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 4L, 11L, 8L, 11L, 5L, 11L, 14L, 18L, 18L, 22L, 21L, 24L, 
6L, 7L, 9L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 21L, 17L), Date = c("31/05/2004", 
"08/06/2004", "09/07/2004", "28/05/2004", "10/06/2004", "11/07/2004", 
"01/06/2004", "04/06/2004", "15/06/2004", "22/04/2007", "30/04/2007", 
"22/05/2007", "18/06/2007", "27/03/2007 1:00", "17/04/2007", 
"06/05/2007", "10/06/2007", "28/03/2007 1:00", "19/04/2007", 
"20/05/2007", "11/06/2007", "26/03/2010 1:00", "30/04/2010", 
"21/05/2010", "25/03/2010 1:00", "16/04/2010", "24/05/2010", 
"28/03/2010", "18/04/2010", "23/05/2010", "13/03/2013 1:00", 
"13/04/2013", "15/05/2013", "15/06/2013", "15/03/2013 1:00", 
"15/04/2013", "14/05/2013", "16/06/2013", "12/03/2013 1:00", 
"14/04/2013", "16/05/2013", "18/06/2013", "23/03/2017 4:50", 
"23/04/2017 3:43", "28/05/2017 3:06", "22/06/2017 2:26", "26/03/2017 4:05", 
"22/04/2017 4:05", "29/05/2017 3:10", "21/06/2017 3:06", "27/03/2017 3:18", 
"24/04/2017 3:32", "25/05/2017 4:26", "29/06/2017 2:33", "24/03/2020 4:05", 
"29/04/2020 21:00", "24/05/2020 2:39", "30/06/2020 21:00", "25/03/2020 4:11", 
"30/04/2020 4:32", "28/05/2020 3:21", "29/06/2020 2:52", "26/03/2020 4:21", 
"28/04/2020 21:00", "30/05/2020 3:21", "28/06/2020 2:29", "26/03/2023 3:51", 
"20/04/2023 3:00", "10/05/2023 2:53", "07/06/2023 2:55", "29/03/2023 3:35", 
"16/04/2023 4:06", "09/05/2023 2:55", "13/06/2023 2:58", "28/03/2023 3:56", 
"19/04/2023 3:08", "14/05/2023 3:00", "06/06/2023 3:00"), Temperature = c(21.9, 
23.1, 26.9, 20.7, 22.7, 27.1, 21.3, 21.1, 23.2, 22.6, 17.7, 20.2, 
23.8, 14.6, 19.9, 22.3, 28.7, 14.7, 16.6, 23.5, 23.5, 14.9, 17.8, 
20, 16.6, 18, 20.8, 16.7, 18.5, 21, 20.7, 17.6, 18.9, 23.4, 26.4, 
17.1, 20.5, 23.3, 25.7, 17, 20, 24.2, 16.9, 18.7, 23.1, 24.8, 
15.7, 29.4, 23.7, 23.9, 15.2, 17.7, 21, 25.8, 16.8, 18.1, 20.6, 
25, 15.4, 17.9, 21.8, 25, 17.9, 18.1, 21, 24.8, 17.5, 19.3, 20.8, 
24, 16.4, 19.4, 19.2, 23.7, 16.9, 25.2, 20.2, 22.6), Solar.Radiation = c(24.3, 
25.9, 24.5, 18.2, 25.7, 24.4, 26.2, 28.3, 22.7, 22.4, 24.6, 25.8, 
21.1, 19.5, 14.9, 22.4, 25.4, 21.1, 25.9, 19.1, 19.1, 11.4, 10.5, 
25.4, 17.7, 21.7, 25.7, 18.3, 20.2, 23, 16.8, 19.6, 22.2, 25.3, 
15.3, 22.8, 23.8, 21.2, 15.6, 23.2, 24.6, 19.4, 16.3, 20.6, 26.6, 
26.2, 21.1, 22, 26.4, 21.1, 16.1, 22.4, 24.9, 25.5, 13.4, 24.3, 
23.6, 19.5, 18.5, 8.7, 26.4, 19.5, 17.2, 24.3, 27.9, 22, 15.7, 
22, 26.3, 26.7, 16.2, 23.6, 25.2, 22.2, 20.4, 20.5, 25.9, 26.3
), Month = c("May", "June", "July", "May", "June", "July", "June", 
"June", "June", "April", "April", "May", "June", "March", "April", 
"May", "June", "March", "April", "May", "June", "March", "April", 
"May", "March", "April", "May", "March", "April", "May", "March", 
"April", "May", "June", "March", "April", "May", "June", "March", 
"April", "May", "June", "March", "April", "May", "June", "March", 
"April", "May", "June", "March", "April", "May", "June", "March", 
"April", "May", "June", "March", "April", "May", "June", "March", 
"April", "May", "June", "March", "April", "May", "June", "March", 
"April", "May", "June", "March", "April", "May", "June"), Sampling.Effort = c(0.75, 
0.75, 0.5, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.5, 0.75, 0.75, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 
0.75, 1, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -78L), groups = structure(list(
    Year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L), levels = c("2004", 
    "2007", "2010", "2013", "2017", "2020", "2023"), class = "factor"), 
    Transect = c("East", "North", "West", "East", "North", "West", 
    "East", "North", "West", "East", "North", "West", "East", 
    "North", "West", "East", "North", "West", "East", "North", 
    "West"), .rows = structure(list(1:3, 4:6, 7:9, 10:13, 14:17, 
        18:21, 22:24, 25:27, 28:30, 31:34, 35:38, 39:42, 43:46, 
        47:50, 51:54, 55:58, 59:62, 63:66, 67:70, 71:74, 75:78), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -21L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: If you are interested in measuring the overall trend over time, why not treat `Year` as a continuous variable rather than an unordered factor variable? If you convert `Year` to a number via `as.numeric(as.character(nestingbirds$Year))` then the exponent of the coefficient for `Year` will tell you the average proportional increase / decrease in counts per year over the length of the study

Comment: @AllanCameron is right, but I would be careful about doing that if the pattern over time isn't close to linear (and it looks like it isn't in your model).  You could be imposing a functional form on the relationship that is not supported by the data and as a consequence, your interpretation of change over time may not be consistent with the data as well.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong yes, though I suppose if we are simply asking the question 'does the data support there having been a significant overall trend up or down, once sampling effort and transept have been taking into account?', then I might take the very small positive coefficient with a p value of 0.3 as a clear 'no'. Or is that overly simplistic?

Comment: @AllanCameron Imagine the case where the trend is significantly positive from 2004-2013 and then significantly negative from 2013-2023.  This could result in a small coefficient.  I suppose that would, in fact, mean that from the beginning to the end, there may have been relatively little change, but it doesn't mean that abundance is unrelated to time.  I guess whether this "works" or not depends on the precise nature of the question.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong sure - the lack of a significant overall trend does not imply that counts are unrelated to time (like if I track daily temperatures between July this year and July next year, I might find there was no significant trend overall, but I'd be wrong to infer that temperature is unrelated to time). That's a good point.